git submodule seems to fail on network locations
Git submodule does not seem to be able to cope with network locations. For example, consider this:
>git submodule init
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 171: cd: //XXXX/temp/git-temp/emacs: Not a directory
Cannot chdir to $cdup, the toplevel of the working tree

I am using the emacs repository as an example here. It doesn't have submodules so I would expect git submodule init to do nothing successfully. It does this away from a network drive.
This is causing me problems because some tools (Pycharm) seem to default to running submodule init while cloning; so they report failure when, actually, the clone is working.
I would welcome any thoughts on how to fix.
